# ASP.NET Core publishing to Azure (Staging)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

VS 2019
ASP.NET Core 3.1

I have developed a Web App locally and now I am ready to deploy to an Azure Staging environment.

My Web App was originally .Net (not Core) and I had not problems deploying it.

How to I tell the deployment process to use the "Staging" environment?

My launchSettings.json contains the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59000",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a appSettings.Staging.json pointing to the Staging database...

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection": "Data Source=myapp.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MyAppCoreStaging;user id=myappstepadmin;password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
}
```

But I am not sure how to tell it to use Staging when I deploy.

At the moment when I deploy, the browser starts up on the page and I get:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
Common solutions to this issue:
The application failed to start
The application started but then stopped
The application started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265
```

Is there something I need to configure on Azure to use the Staging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are deploying to Azure and didn't specify that you are using a CI/CD Pipeline as your method of publishing, I assume that you are using the publishing profiles provided from Azure portal directly in Visual Studio.

In the Publish dialog, click on Edit -> settings -> Configuration and select Stage

In your Program.cs, your `CreateWebHostBuilder` (assuming you are using ASP.NET Core 3.0+; it's also possible for 2.2 but it's not `IWebHostBuilder`), you can specify that the appsettings file should be dependent on your solution configuration:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseEnvironment(Environment);
```

where `Environment` can be a property with preprocessor directives:

```
public static string Environment
{
    get
    {
        string environmentName;
#if DEBUG
        environmentName = "development";
#elif STAGE
        environmentName = "staging";
#elif RELEASE
        environmentName = "production";
#endif
        return environmentName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will investigate later and see if it helps.

Comment: This is the first time I have done this.  I have created a Staging solution Configuration, but where do I set the STAGE pre-processor directive, so that it is applied when I use the Staging solution configuration?

Comment: The preprocessor directive `STAGE` is called like that since thats the name of the solution configration. USE  `#elif STAGING` instead

Comment: OK.  Making progress, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use a build pipeline, you should look at this.

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '-o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) /p:EnvironmentName=Staging'
```